# Annoying sticky CTRL key when connecting to Linux server with NoMachine from Windows

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, nomachine

When I connect to Debian Linux, keyboard behaves as if CTRL has been pressed before I've connected. I have to press it each time I connect to make my mouse and keyboard work the right way. Is there any trick to fix this NoMachine issue? My Linux version is the following:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

NoMachine version is 8.8.1, updated both on client and server. `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` gives `MATE`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any trick to fix this NoMachine issue?

Yes, by updating to NoMachine 8.9.1.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me, after update ALT button become sticky.